# how to read data from csv file into C# console Application

Tags: c#-4.0

```
using System;
namespace jagged_array
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string[][] Members = new string[10][]{
new string[]{"amit","amit@gmail.com",         "9999999999"},
new string[]{"chandu","chandu@gmail.com","8888888888"},
new string[]{"naveen","naveen@gmail.com", "7777777777"},
new string[]{"ramu","ramu@gmail.com",       "6666666666"},
new string[]{"durga","durga@gmail.com",     "5555555555"},
new string[]{"sagar","sagar@gmail.com",      "4444444444"},
new string[]{"yadav","yadav@gmail.com",    "3333333333"},
new string[]{"suraj","suraj@gmail.com",        "2222222222"},
new string[]{"niharika","niharika@gmail.com","11111111111"},
new string[]{"anusha","anusha@gmail.com",  "0000000000"},
};

for (int i =0; i < Members.Length; i++)
{
System.Console.Write("Name List ({0}):", i + 1);
for (int j = 0; j < Members[i].Length; j++)
{
System.Console.Write(Members[i][j] + "\t");
}
System.Console.WriteLine();
}``
Console.ReadKey();
}
}
}
```

---

The above is the code for my C# console program in which i used jagged array and i assigned values manually but now my requirement is 'without assigning manually into array i want the same details to import into my program from an csv file(which is at some location in my disc). So how to do it what functions should i make use , please help me with some example. Thank you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main()
        {
            string csv_file_path=@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv";

            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

            Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        {
            DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

            try
            {

            using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
                {
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                    }

                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return csvData;
        }
```

Comment: That `catch` clause is pure evil; not only does it discard error messages, but if you get an error it will return the wrong answer without any indication something went wrong. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the CSV file like an excel workbook and you will find a lot of examples on the web for what you need to do.

```
ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile();

// Loads file.
ef.LoadCsv("filename.csv");

// Selects first worksheet.
ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into details, but you can read lines text from a file with [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).
Once you have those lines, you can split them into parts using [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) (at least this will work if the CSV file contains very simple information as in your example).